# Match escaped character and escaping character itself between delimiters

Tags: regex, escaping, delimiter

## Problem

Suppose you have a string which contains one or more random character sequences or words being delimited by a certain character, lets say a single quote. Single quotes not being a delimiter are escaped by a backslash.

***For example:***

*String*

> 'word' 'word word' 'word\'word' '\' '\\' '\''

*Desired capturing*

1. 'word'
2. 'word word'
3. 'word\'word'
4. '\'
5. '\\'
6. '\''

Essentially every sequence of characters between non-escaped single quotes have to be captured.

## Difficulties

Capturing #4 and #5 both have a single quote delimiter being escaped by a backslash. In fact this should be read as just a backslash between single quote delimiters.

So far I have been able to capture everything but #6. I used to following regex:

> '((\\'[^\s]|[^'])*)'

I found this rather odd because I thought this would capture every sequence of characters between single quotes not containing a single quote with the exception of a escaped single quote followed by a non-whitespace character. Therefore I don't know why #6 is not captured by this expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to match all characters that are not a quote or any characters escaped with a backslash (including the single quote or the backslash itself):

```
'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)*)'
```

To make this pattern efficient, you can rewrite it like this (without the alternation):

```
'([^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*)'
```

Comment: I did a quick test but I don't think this is the correct solution either: http://regexr.com/3bmtc
. Or is this test just wrong? Your solution works if I also escape the backslash itself, which makes sense.

Comment: @Pascal: to be more clear, I think your desired result is wrong. (item 4 in particular that must be `'\' '`)

Comment: I think you are correct. I guess I got caught by tunnel vision. Thanks for clearing up this problem. I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
'(?:[^'\\]|\\'(?!\s))*'|'\\+'
```

You can use this instead.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/35

Comment: This solve this specific example but doesn't capture three or more backslashes between single quote as mentioned in the initial problem. Note that I want it to be able to capture every sequence of characters between single quotes (with single quotes not being a delimiter escaped)

Comment: I'm quite impressed. However I think it's better to solve this problem by escaping characters correctly. Still +1 for your answer.